# Fluid dynamics: Euler equation and turbulence

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, navier-stokes, turbulence

I have a doubt, a sort of paradox. It is known that the classical [Navier-Stokes equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) in the limit of [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) that goes to infinity - the high Reynolds regime - gives the classical [Euler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)) (see this question for a [definition of "Re"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272738/226902) and this for the [Euler limit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293926/226902) at high Re).

**Question:** Since flows at a high Reynolds number become quickly fully turbulent (see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/371500/226902)), I am wondering whether all the ideal fluids, for which Euler's equation is valid, are prone to turbulence.

Comment: This question is closely related,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/725566/226902 "Is turbulence more likely to form with the Euler equation as opposed to Navier-Stokes?". This is extremely interesting and also related, but has no answer yet: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731278/226902 "Turbulence, Euler equations and equipartition of energy"